# Code Ingnitor - Home page works.. All other pages have 404 error

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, vhosts

When accessing from ######1.co.uk (which has an SSL) to document root ###/production everything works fine.

However when accessing ###/production from ######2.co.uk (which doesn't have an SSL - set up in the vhost file) the home page displays fine but the other pages are returning a 404.

Here's the entry in the vhost file that points #####2.co.uk to ###/production

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/####/production"
    ServerName #####2.co.uk
    ErrorLog "/etc/httpd/logs/####.error.log"
    CustomLog "/etc/httpd/logs/####.log" common

    <Directory /var/www/html/####/preprod>

            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "Authentication Required"
            AuthUserFile "/var/www/html/secure/.htpasswd"
            Require valid-user

            order allow,deny
            allow from all
            AllowOverride all

    </Directory>

    <Location /api/sms>
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "Authentication Required"
            AuthUserFile "/var/www/html/secure/.htpasswd"
            Require valid-user
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

Done a quick google search and this could be down to the .htaccess file in ###/production

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#Old website redirects
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.aspx$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/ [QSA,NC,R=301,L]
RewriteRule default/?$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/home/ [NC,R=301,L]

#SSL Redirects
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [L]


# Codigniter Page Handling
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|content|assets|files|flash|uploads|xml|private/uploads|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Any ideas as to what the problem is?

Also note that the Directory of #####2.co.uk is set to

```
<Directory /var/www/html/####/preprod>
```

Which is different to the Document Root.

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/####/production"
```

Comment: What are your config settings set to?  Variables like $config['index_page'], $config['base_url'], etc.

Comment: index_page and base_url are both ''

Comment: You'll need to put something in the base_url.  It will likely be similar or the same as what the "ServerName #####2.co.uk" is.

Comment: I'll try that solution thank you...

Comment: What will happen with "RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [L] " this forces https but #####2.co.uk doesn't have an SSL.

Comment: Also, how come ######1.co.uk works without the base_url ?

Comment: You can remove the HTTPS rule from the htaccess file.  As for your question on working without a base URL...it is because your host is setup to hit the index file in the wwwroot directory.  Per the notes in the config, "If this is not set then CodeIgniter will try guess the protocol, domain and path to your installation. However, you should always configure this explicitly and never rely on auto-guessing, especially in production environments."